# Having trouble removing an excess face

Tags: faces, extrude

one of the faces on my model seems to be covering an indent that I made.

In wire mode, both indents are visible, yet in solid mode, one of my indents is covered by a face. When I try to select the face, it selects the entire face around it. I'm not sure how I should fix this[image: left indent covered]
[image: wire frame looks fine][image: selects everything]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE, the entire face is being selected because looks like it is one face, apparently you have overlapping faces, if I were you I would delete the massive face, and reselect the edges the way I want to have faces, and fill them again with <F>. Aside from this issue, read the meta of BSE to know your way around, and welcome again to BSE.  I'll vote to close this question since I don't believe it's going to provide help to others in the future.

Comment: alright thanks George!

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable auto merge and split edges with value of 0.001, select everything is involved and hit G and ENTER without actually moving the mesh.

[image: automerge]

If this won't help and you still don't want to delete anything you can duplicate and separate the boundary circle of the indent and use it as for knife project to cut your giant face. Make sure nothing is overlapping and the mesh is clean while you working like when you connect two vertices along a face, F and J does different things and you might miss it or there always could be overlapping verts or edges. You can keep auto merge enabled in situations where you can missout something.